# Why are the nav link tags sometimes behaving incorrectly?

Tags: html, css

I want the colors of the text and background to change when clicked, and also the selected page button to have that inverted style. When i open it with a localink everything looks fine, but when i upload it to the server and i open it for the first time the links are more spaced out and the background color extends on the margin. Why is that? If i refresh it, it looks fine, but if i Ctrl+F5 to clear the cache the problem returns. And I dont know why but this issue happens only on portrait.

You can look on the website cristianleciu.com for the issue , and also i have linked 2 images, showing how its supposed to look, and how the problem looks like.

Thank you in advance.

[This is how its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qMC6.png)

[This is how the problem looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf4PE.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="title">
                <span>Cristian Leciu</span>
            </div>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li class="selected">HOME</li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTOFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    <style>

.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:1000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100pt;
    line-height: 40%;
}

nav{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px 0;
    z-index: 10000;
} 
.navlist {
    padding-top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navlist a{
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navlist a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.selected{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (min-width:160px) and (orientation:portrait){
    .title{
        font-size: 118px;
        margin-top: 5.45vh;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Tai Heritage Pro', serif;
        line-height: 100%;
    }
    nav{
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
    .navlist a, .selected{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}

    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: The mentioned URL doesn't show that kind of problem for me. You most likely have an older version of your stylesheet in your browser cache already, I suppose ... What happens when you visit the page in a private window?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<a>` tag in your code.

```
    <ul class="navlist">
       <li class="selected">HOME</li>
       <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTOFOLIO</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>
```

You need to fix that first as your css rules is targeting the `.navlist a`
So first you need to fix your HTML like this:

```
<ul class="navlist">
   <li class="selected"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTOFOLIO</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: technical incorrect. There are CSS declarations for `.selected` which is a stand-alone selector and not specified with an anchor. As such adding an anchor is not required.

Comment: You are definitely right @tacoshy, i missed that, thanks. I have edited my answer to remove the last part. But for the rest of the answer I believe I am right saying that the <a> tag is missing. If yes please remove the negative vote. Thanks